# Regex match for complete string only (max. characters)

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex to match following 'good' values.

```
100.100.100.10
100.100.100.1
100.100.100
100.100.10
100.100.1
100.100
```

Following conditions need to be valid:

- Minimum of 7 characters (xxx.xxx)
- Maximum of 14 characters (xxx.xxx.xxx.xx)
- Groups can contain max 3 characters (xxx)
- Groups need to be separated by a '.'
- In case of 3 groups, the third group can contain 1 to 3 characters (x or xx or xxx)
- In case of 4 groups, the fourth group can contain 1 to 2 characters (x or xx)
- All previous groups need to contain 3 characters (xxx)

To test the validity of a string value, following regex has been created.

```
 ([0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]{3}){2}(\.[0-9]{1,2}))|
 ([0-9]{3}(\.[0-9]{3})(\.[0-9]{1,3})?)
```

I had to use the OR operator, but can't find how I can exclude values containing more than 14 characters. I've tested the below 'bad' examples (via http://regexr.com/) and do get a match on PART of the string. However, my rule would have to be NOT to accept these strings, since there's 'noise' at the end of each 'word' (whereas the word is considered a string without spaces)

```
100.100.100.100.100
```

The last .100 needs to make the full string invalid, no partial match is accepted. Adding \b or ^$ in combination with the OR does not provide me the required result.

```
100.100.100.100100  
100.100.100100100 
100.100.100.100
```

The above need to invalid as well.

Comment: Is there *no way* you could use other tools other than regexps? It doesn't seem good for the purpose.

Comment: So, `100.100.100.100` should not match?

Comment: @Wiktor, no since it exceeds the max. length of 14 chars.

Comment: Then my answer is what you need. No lookarounds, pure groupings, will work in most regex flavors, even in Go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use optional groups:

```
^[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jt90qM/1)

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
  -`[0-9]{3}` - 3 digits (your group 1)
- `\.[0-9]{3}` - a dot and 3 digits (group 2)
- `(?:\.[0-9]{1,3}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?)?` - an optional group matching

  - `\.[0-9]{1,3}` - a dot and 1 to 3 digits (Group 3)
  - `(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?` - an optional group (group 4):

    - `\.` - a dot
    - `[0-9]{1,2}` - any 1 to 2 digits
- `$` - end of string

Answer (score 0):

Logically, there's 1-3 complete groups, followed by a partial group:

```
^(?=.{7,14})(\d{3}\.){1,3}\d{1,3}$
```

The look ahead enforces the length.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/7aa8Fphtzq).

Comment: No, it does not. It matches the 1st "noise" value.

Comment: Huh? See demo link.

Comment: Yes, it matches `100.100.100.100` (15 chars) while the requirement is *Maximum of 14 charachters*.

Comment: @wik not any more... (question edited to correct misleading/incorrect data)

Comment: Look: *In case of 4 groups, the fourth group can contain 1 to 2 charachters (x or xx)*. You have `\d{1,3}` at the end of string allowing 1 to 3

Comment: @wiktor please follow link and see for yourself that this answer is correct

Comment: @wik question (and answer) edited again for clarity.

Comment: @wiktor to be clear, even though I defined the last group as `\d{1,3}`, the look ahead locks the length to 7-14, thus preventing the *4th* group from having 3 chars (ie a 15 char input), or the first group from having less than 3.